# Extending the Session in PHP with gc_maxlifetime not working

Tags: php, session, php-ini

I have the following code to extend my `$_SESSION[]` variables. They expire after around 2-3 hours.

I tried to extend to 22h by changing the `session.gc_maxlifetime`, but im still losing my session after a couple of hours.

```
//start sessions
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*22); // 22h - one day

//Output just to make sure config was changed.
echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime"); 

session_start();
```

How do I increase the duration of my session?

Comment: 22h is one day? did i miss something?

Comment: w/e changed it to 24h, 22h was to avoid relogging at 9am during work. it would log you out at around 7am, then you login at 9am.

Comment: @mata maybe because he wants to prevents automatic logouts when the user opens the browser every morning at the same time !? i think this is a very clever solution.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple php.ini's for a site it may use the shortest session.gc_maxlifetime for all sites that share the same cache folder.  since by default every session file is in the same place if a garbage collect is run it is run on all files in the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could be: session.cookie_lifetime which by default is 0, meaning terminate on closing of browser.

If you close your client and open it again session.gc_maxlifetime doesn't matter--it only applies to non-terminated sessions.

Or, you may have calles session start somewhere else earlier, with a smaller session.gc_maxlifetime.  Often frameworks set this.  Repeat calls to session start do nothing to alter the session.

Comment: I can close and reopen my browser, my sessions are ok.

Comment: @EtienneDupuis what is your session.cookie_lifetime set to?

Comment: Also, check your session cookie in your browser and see what the lifetime is...  It should be at least as long as you pick for the gc_maxlifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it in the php.ini ! As session lifetime is a filesystem thing, a per-script set up is always problematical.

Answer (score 0):

There's a note [on the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) about this; if another script using the same directory to store session data doesn't have the maxlifetime set, it'll use the shorter value instead.